# Import maps in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, export, import

It's possible to export and import maps from one google's account to another? I had an account in google maps and when I changed my e-mail, I started to use Google Maps associated with this new login. I would like to import the maps of the old account to this new one. It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share maps from your old account to your new account by using the Collaboration feature. I don't believe it's possible to share all of them at once; you'd have to do them individually.

Go to Google Maps, and click on "My places" on the left sidebar. Find the map you want to move over. Click on it, then click the "collaborate" link. From there, invite yourself as the collaborator, then send the invitation. You'll then be able to access the map from your new account.